# wildfly-maven-plugin wildfly:start blocks if management-port is not 9990

Tags: wildfly-maven-plugin

The **behavior of `wildfly:start`** (Maven-Goals of the wildfly-maven-plugin) **seems wrong when I change the (management-)port** (see  https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/examples/run-example.html for description).

`wildfly:start` should not block further execution while `wildfly:run` should so (see https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/plugin-info.html for the description). Since I am automatically publishing to a JBoss-server, I'd expect it to startup and then publish, but whenever I change the management-port, it blocks further execution (until the startup-timeout expires) and then the build fails.

> [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: HTTP-Management Interface ist empfangsbereit auf http://127.0.0.1:9990/Management

*Means something along the lines of "HTTP-Management Interface is listening on `http://127.0.0.1:9990/Management`".*

Why is it listening on port `9990` even though I told it to listen on port `9995`?

> 18:15:49,813 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.1.0.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.10.Final-redhat-1) wurde gestartet in 35339ms - 2625 von 2851 Diensten gestartet (379 Services sind "lazy", passiv oder werden bei Bedarf geladen)

*Means something along the lines of "JBoss EAP 7.1.0.GA (...) was started successfully in 35339ms - 265 of 2851 services started (379 services are lazy, passive or are started on demand).*

It's this message it hangs after - waiting for the startup-timeout to expire and failing thereafter.

Here's a minimal pom.xml showing the problem:

```
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.install.skip>true</maven.install.skip>
        <jar.skipIfEmpty>true</jar.skipIfEmpty>

        <plugin.wildfly.port>9995</plugin.wildfly.port>
        <plugin.wildfly.httpport>8050</plugin.wildfly.httpport>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jboss-home>D:\server\jboss-eap-7.1</jboss-home>
                    <username>admin</username>
                    <password>admin</password>
                    <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                    <port>${plugin.wildfly.port}</port>
                    <java-opts>
                        <java-opt>-Djboss.http.port=${plugin.wildfly.httpport}</java-opt>
                    </java-opts>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-server</id>

                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If I change the property `plugin.wildfly.port` **back to** `9990` (default management port), `wildfly:start` becomes **non-blocking** again.

Comment: Have you tried passing the `-Djboss.management.http.port=${plugin.wildfly.port}` in the `java-opt`? Or do you have it configured in your `standalone.xml`?

Comment: Thank you @JamesR.Perkins. I have not tried it yet, but I will do so within the next few days. However still: this odd behavior does look like a bug to me, doesn't it?

Comment: It only blocks for the length of the timeout to determine if the server is running.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins if you could post your previous comment as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it, because this is how it finally worked out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've not overridden the management port in your server configuration you'd need to pass `-Djboss.management.http.port=${plugin.wildfly.port}` as a `java-opt` as well.

Note too the blocking should only last as long as the timeout while plugin attempts to determine if the server is running.